# How to setup automatic SSH-tunnel to remote machine in vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I've created a provisioner script which helps me to create an SSH tunnel to a remote machine from within my vagrant box (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) every time the box is started.

Interesting part of my Vagrantfile:

```
config.ssh.forward_agent = true
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "setuptunnel.sh", run: "always", privileged: false
```

And the setuptunnel.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -NL 5432:localhost:5432 me@remotemachine &> /tmp/sshtunnel.log &
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "successfully created ssh tunnel."
else
    echo "error creating ssh tunnel."
fi
```

But when I ssh into vagrant, the tunnel was not created. Looking into */tmp/sshtunnel.log* shows me:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'remotemachine,1.2.3.4.5' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Running the ssh-command manually successfully establishes the tunnel. So it looks like as if agent-forwarding does not work when the provisioners are run?

Comment: What OS do you use on host machine?

Comment: @Alik: It's elementaryOS 0.3 which is based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The Vagrant version is 1.7.2.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: yes you're right. I will close it here.

Comment: @Marc, I am not sure, that your question is offtopic here, on SO. It covers a tool (vagrant/ssh-agent) used by developers, so for me it is on-topic

Comment: I've flagged the question for a moderator... I also think that it is interesting for developers, as Vagrant is a common tool in software development. Let us see :-)

Comment: @Marc add something like `ssh-add -L` into `setuptunnel.sh` to make sure agent forwarding doesn't work during provisioning stage

Comment: Yes I've added the contents of the following lines to the script:
`echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK > /tmp/SSH_AUTH_SOCK; echo $USER >> /tmp/SSH_AUTH_SOCK; ls -l $SSH_AUTH_SOCK >> /tmp/SSH_AUTH_SOCK; ssh-add -l >> /tmp/SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

and it outputs me:

`/tmp/ssh-pfAa5EKO1I/agent.1219
vagrant
srwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Jun 3 11:30 /tmp/ssh-pfAa5EKO1I/agent.1219
2048 ad:83:cd:65:b9:5b:18:07:4e:7a:d3:76:a7:de:ed:34 marc@marc-HP-ProBook-4730s (RSA)`

Comment: Is `ad:83:cd:65:b9:5b:18:07:4e:7a:d3:76:a7:de:ed:34` the key you can use to connect to the remote machine?

Comment: Is it possible that the agent only can use my identity files, when I actively ssh into the vagrant host?

Comment: @Alik yes this key works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79512/discussion-between-alik-and-marc).

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this? I'm about to try this very same thing I believe and wanted to see what pain I was in for...